# Can you connect to a VPN through an SSH reverse tunnel?

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel, vpn-client

Say I have two machines, both running Linux;

Machine A is running a VPN server and is behind a NAT.

Machine B is the VPN client.

Machine A creates a reverse SSH tunnel from itself to Machine B, exposing a port on Machine B that connects back to the VPN running on Machine A.

How can I connect to Machine A's VPN server from Machine B through the SSH reverse tunnel?

Comment: I've seen something similar done with this using iptables; askubuntu.com/questions/324685/how-to-route-all-internet-traffic-through-tor-the-onion-router

Answer (score 2):

A SSH tunnel only works with TCP, so your VPN server must be configured to use TCP for connections. You connect the the tunnel endpoint on Machine B just as you would connect to Machine A. In other words, just replace the ip address and destination port in your client configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have this setup:

- Machine B has public domain machine.b and port 22 will access SSH server of Machine B.
- Machine A has local IP address 192.168.10.2 and its VPN server uses port 1194.

Steps to setup a VPN connection through reverse SSH connection:

- Machine A establishes an SSH connection to Machine B with this command: ssh -i "/path/to/key/file" -R 2500:192.168.10.2:1194 user@machine.b -p 22
- Machine B establishes a VPN connection to 127.0.0.1:2500

As the result, connection from Machine B to port 2500 of localhost (127.0.0.1) will be redirected through the SSH tunnel and go to port 1194 of 192.168.10.20 on Machine A, which is the VPN server of Machine A.

I always use this setup as my DIY VPN server in case the company's VPN is in maintenance.